# What is a good choice for a windowmanager for temporary use?

Tags: debian, window-manager, chrome, ratpoison

Ratpoison is my windowmanager of choice and am running a fairly recent version of google chrome and I wish to drag a couple tabs between windows. This used to work, but recent changes in chrome makes it more difficult to drag tabs into a window with ratpoison. So for a couple minutes I need another window manager that does not automatically resize all windows. Fortunately ratpoison has the ability to run another window manager and sleep until the other window manager is done. Exactly what I need, except that the window managers I have tried this with make sure that they cleanup on exit (close windows, restart the x server, etc.) and this interferes with my plans.

What is a simple window manager that allows overlapping windows and exits  cleanly? I would prefer one that is packaged for debian, but I am willing to compile. I have no other requirements including ease of use. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using awesome myself, so I checked it's source code to see if I could find a cleanup function. I haven't tested this, but you can try to comment out his line near the end of main() in awesome.c: awesome_atexit(false)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried, but I suggest looking at [twm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twm) or one of its derivatives for a simple, old-school stacking window manager. Or you may try a flexible, scriptable, but not invasive stacking window manager such as [Fvwm](http://www.fvwm.org/) or [Sawfish](http://sawfish.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page).